# foreach function not working in Spark DataFrame

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

According to DataFrames API, definition is:

```
public void foreach(scala.Function1<Row,scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> f)
```

Applies a function f to all rows.

But when I am trying like

```
Dataframe df = sql.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header","true")
    .load("file:///home/hadoop/Desktop/examples.csv");

df.foreach(x->
{
   System.out.println(x);
});
```

I am getting compile time error. any mistake?

Comment: I downvoted because you need to add the error message to the question.

Comment: I have downvoted this question for many reasons. First, the error message isn't available thus it falls in the category of why my code isn't working. Secondly, for the usage of `foreach` to print output. Third because there is a typo. `DataFrame` is with a big F ! I'm also voting to close the question for the matter.

Comment: I upvoted this question because I ended up with the same problem. There are two problems in compilation:   1. the parameter `Function1<Row, BoxedUnit>` does not seem to fit Java lambdas   2. if the parameter is    
`df.foreach(new AbstractFunction1<Row, BoxedUnit>() {    @Override  public BoxedUnit apply(Row arg0) {  return null;  }  });`,
, it works just fine.

Comment: The second error is _The method foreach(Function1<Row,BoxedUnit>) in the type DataFrame is not applicable for the arguments ((Row x) -> {})_ (or _((Row x, BoxedUnit b) -> {})_)

Answer (score 7):

You can cast it as Java RDD in order to use the lambda as you which:

```
df.toJavaRDD().foreach(x->
   System.out.println(x)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

First extend `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1` and implement Serializable like below

```
public abstract class SerializableFunction1<T,R> 
      extends AbstractFunction1<T, R> implements Serializable 
{
}
```

Now use this `SerializableFunction1` class like below.

```
df.foreach(new SerializableFunction1<Row,BoxedUnit>(){
        @Override
        public BoxedUnit apply(Row row) {
            System.out.println(row.get(0));
            return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        }
});
```

Comment: could you please elaborate the "BoxedUnit.UNIT". What does it means?

Comment: Unit is the equivalent of scala to void in Java . 

The BoxedUnit is an internal type related to the JVM that usually shouldn't be available in the API, but as someone else put it "sometimes it leaks to the interface".

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
df.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>(){ public void call(String line) {
          //your function code here
}});
```

If you want just to show df content, this much easier :

```
df.show();
```

Comment: @user6325753 can you add the error message to your question please ?

Comment: new VoidFunction should be new ForeachFunction instead.